# getter value in angular throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError for the getter value I'm using in my component

```
public get selectedRows() {
  if (this.gridApi) {
    return this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML code where I'm using this selectedRows

```
<div *ngIf="selectedRows && selectedRows.length > 0" class="btn-cls">
  <button>submit</button>
</div>
```

I tried [hidden] instead of *ngIf but still getting the same error.

Comment: You might need the async pipe as I assume getSelectedRows is an async operation?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve my issue using ngDoCheck instead of getter

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
  if (this.gridApi && this.gridApi.getSelectedRows() && this.gridApi.getSelectedRows().length > 0) {
    this.isRowSelected = true;
  } else {
    this.isRowSelected = false;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="isRowSelected" class="btn-more">
  <button>submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception thrown is how Angular prevent inconsistency between the data model and view, therefore wrong or old data is not shown to the final user. Please check that link out: https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/

The link above will help to understand how Angular avoid inconsistency in data during the change detection process, and will probably help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: if the link is still broken, this might help: https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4